# Transform multiple layers as one unit in ArcGIS 10?

Tags: arcmap, coordinate-system, georeferencing

The general/conceptual question:

Is there a way to transform multiple layers together in ArcMap 10 (on Windows XP SP3) as one unit?

More specifically:

I have an ArcMap document with a georeferenced raster layer on the bottom (say, aerial photography) that has been digitised with layers of polygons and points representing different features in the raster.

It turns out that I need to re-georeference the raster in a way that will change the skew/shape of the raster, and the polygon and points layers will no longer match. To prevent me from having to re-digitise everything in the raster layer, is there a way for me to re-georeference all those layers together as one unit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Export from the Data Frame (**not** the Map Layout) a GeoTiff:

TIFF (Tagged Image File Format)

TIFF files are the best choice for importing into image editing applications and are also a common GIS raster data format. However, they cannot be natively viewed by a Web browser. ArcMap **TIFFs exported from the data view also support georeferencing information** in GeoTIFF tags or in a separate world file for use as raster data.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00sm00000004000000

If you have (vector) layers you can use the spatial adjustment tools to skew/rotate/scale the vector and raster with displacement links (can be save out separately)

[image]

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/About_spatial_adjustment_transformations/001t000000tv000000/